# How do I count the no of occurrences in a file using grep but with a condition that the occurrences are greater than zero?

Tags: unix, grep

I am currently using a grep command:

```
zgrep -c 'hello' *2017-05-08*
```

Which counts the total no. of occurrences of the keyword with files having the following name within the **. For example, the output shows like:

```
log.2017-05-08-15.gz:0
log.2017-05-08-16.gz:0
log.2017-05-08-17.gz:1
```

It returns a list of files which has the number of occurrences.However, I want only the files which have more than 0 occurrences such as the third file above.

```
log.2017-05-08-17.gz:1
```

Can anyone please tell me how could I achieve the desired result. Please let me know if you have any questions

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe this isn't a good answer, but see if this works:

```
zgrep -c 'hello' *2017-05-08* | grep -v ":0"
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. But it takes a long time. Do you know if we can speed up the search ?.

Comment: The wait is likely due to the decompression. grep itself is actually incredibly fast, but zgrep has to decompress the file to do the searching

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation. I am fairly new to grep and find it a bit hard to understand the nuances. Can you tell me what the -v option is for ?

Comment: -v is 'exclude from the results'; basically the inverse of regular grep.

Comment: Great, Thanks !!